# How to send ALL XML messages that were sent when the database was down TO PeopleSoft after database picks up?

Tags: xml, database, esb, mule, peoplesoft

I am working on a project using MULE ESB.

The present scenario in the application I am working is

From the first application we are able to send xml msgs to peoplesoft (its acting as the second application) directly but it is not guaranteeing that all the messages will be received at the peoplesoft end.

so we decided using MULE in between first and second application. Is this a good choice?

Could you help with a better choice wrt the architecture so that the peoplesoft receives all the messages that were sent

Looking forward for help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough about your architecture to give you a definitive answer but what you are describing is a pretty common use case for Mule ESB. If you need to guarantee message delivery to PeopleSoft, you may want to have Mule write the messages to a queue first.

Some more information on this type of pattern in Mule - http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Bridge+Pattern